# Saving and Filtering Favourites from a UITableViewController without Core Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am building a simple informational based app that provides the users with built in Leaflets and Images to view, on a variety of topics. It's a `UITabBar` -based application where the first tab is a list of Leaflets, the second is a list of Videos and the third is a list of Languages. Each tab is represented by a `UITableViewController`.

I would like to set up a favouriting mechanism where users can swipe across any leaflet or video in the `UITableViewCell` and "favourite" it. Whichever they favourite will then get added to the 4th tab called (unimaginatively), Favourites.

I'm not using `Core Data` with this application because there's no real need to do that and because I'm quite new to this concept, I'm wondering on the best way to save up to 50 favourites. How would I store this? Would I use something like a `NSUserDefault` for example?

It's a broad question because I've looked online and I'm not quite sure how to approach this.

I would really appreciate if anyone had any guides or thoughts on how to firstly save this and secondly, how to fetch the favourites for the favourites tab. Would/Could I use something like a NSFetchedResultsController even though I'm not using `Core Data`?

Should I just use `Core Data` with this, to save the favourites?

Any thoughts on this would really be appreciated.

Comment: yep, just use Core Data and you will learn by an example

Comment: Yes, and fetched results controller, which is for Core Data, is the best way to display data in a table view.

Comment: Thanks @ogres and Mundi - I thought so and I've used that before on another app, but thought there might just be an easier way with this.